# How to save abbreviation in fish?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, fedora, fish

Running `abbr --add ro rpm-ostree` will set the abbreviation and it works as expected. But once I exit the shell with `exit` and then re-enter the shell by typing `fish` again, all abbreviations are lost. Is it typical behaviour? How to save the abbreviations permanently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/abbr.html), you should just place your definitions in `config.fish` [file](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/language.html#configuration) for them to load at the start.

Command for default location and your example:

```
echo "abbr --add ro rpm-ostree" >> ~/.config/fish/config.fish
```

Comment: Great, I wish these showed that some other people started answering, so that you don't waste time on sending pretty much the same answer at the same time. I guess I'll add some more info to make it different.

Comment: https://7esl.com/great-minds-think-alike/

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation at
[abbr - manage fish abbreviations](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/abbr.html),
you should put the `abbr --add` in the
[config.fish file](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/language.html#configuration).

This way the abbreviation will always be recreated when fish is started.